# remove empty string with sed in ksh

Tags: sed

I have a command, whose output is:

```
""
"D"
"M"
"N"
```

I want to remove the first empty string, so did:

```
<command> |sed 's/^""$/d'
```

But the shell told me:

```
sed: 0602-404 Function s/^""$/d cannot be parsed.
```

So, what `sed` command shall I use to remove the empty string surrounded by double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you missed a quote and you shouldn't use `s///` form :

```
<command> | sed '/^""$/d'
```

And from your comments, if you need to treat only line 1 :

```
<command> | sed '1{/^""$/d}'
```

The `d` modifier is allowed only in `/regex/` form, not in `s///` substitutions form.

Comment: It works! Many thanks! By the way, is there a way to apply this sed expression only to the first line of output?

Comment: it remove ALL line having empty string  and second only 1st line that have an empty string

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 'H
$ {x;s/""\n/²/1;s/.*²//;p;}' YourFile
```

Use of the temporary marker `²` (or any other not used/special Regex char)